# How to detect duplicate pages in ASP.NET Razor Pages in RCLs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

We have a bunch of modules. They are written as [Razor Class Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Then we reuse them in a central application.

Each module is authored by an individual developer and we have encountered an error that we want to find a solution for.

Sometimes developers name stuff like each other, for example `Post`.

Then we see that they have these structures in their RCLs:

Blog module:

- Pages

  - Post

    - List.cshtml

Ticketing module:

- Pages

  - Post

    - List.cshtml

This means that only one `List.cshtml` would be loaded and would override the other one.

We want to find a way to detect these duplicate naming and prevent them.

We tried to find the routes and pages using this code:

```
    var Pages = new List<string>();
    var Routes = new List<string>();
    foreach (var endpoint in EndpointsDataSource.Endpoints)
    {
        foreach (var metadata in endpoint.Metadata)
        {
            if (metadata is PageActionDescriptor)
            {
                Pages.Add(((PageActionDescriptor)metadata).RelativePath);
            }
            if (metadata is PageRouteMetadata)
            {
                Routes.Add(((PageRouteMetadata)metadata).PageRoute);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, **metadata** has already excluded one of the duplicate pages.

What can we do to prevent that?